# How do I use paginate with 'cursors' in N1ql?

Tags: couchbase, sql++, database-cursor

I need to paginate a Couchbase N1ql Query.

I am [aware of pagination](https://blog.couchbase.com/offset-keyset-pagination-n1ql-query-couchbase/) with `OFFSET`, but it is more efficient to designate the start and end point.

I see documentation about `startkey_docid`, but none about how to us this in N1ql.

How do I paginate with cursors, or something similar, in N1ql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into "keyset pagination", a general technique for improving pagination performance by leveraging the index instead of using `offset`. A commonly cited article on the topic is Markus Winand's "[We need tool support for keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)."

For a Couchbase-specific example that uses N1QL, see Keshav Murthy's article "[Database Pagination: Using OFFSET and Keyset in N1QL](https://blog.couchbase.com/offset-keyset-pagination-n1ql-query-couchbase/)."

Comment: Makes sense but what about startkey_docid? It seems like a different approach, also efficient. Is that available for me to use?

Comment: @JoshuaFox `startkey_docid` is only for views, not available for N1QL.

Answer (score 2):

N1QL does not support cursors. Behind the scenes, every query sent to the query engine is a separate HTTP request. There is simply no continuity between queries, and therefore no concept of cursors is supported.

Comment: Ok, so how do I do pagination (other than with OFFSET, which is inefficient)?

Comment: If you are going to paginate using the database, OFFSET and LIMIT are your only choices. If that won't do, you'll have to pull the entire result into a higher level of the system (the app server, maybe?) and paginate from there. You can make this second option less heavyweight by fetching doc ids rather than complete documents and filling in the document contents only when they are needed.

Comment: Thank you . It seems that  Pagination is an important feature for pretty much any application. Do you know why only the OFFSET is offered here? Couchbase does have startkey_docid, so clearly the Couchbase designers are aware of this.

Comment: It's true that Couchbase does not support cursors, but "keyset pagination" might give better performance than paginating with OFFSET and LIMIT. I put some links in another answer.

Comment: The REST API that supports startkey_docid is very inefficient with large data sets, it's really only good for getting the first thousand or so keys. N1QL can work with "primary indexes" which allow you to search using, "meta().id > x and meta().id < y". Primary indexes should be used with extreme caution, since they can lead to full database scans if you aren't careful.